# Bootstrap layout for multiple divs with offset

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I want to create a html page with first row which has a sidebar menu and div for showing the KPI metrics. I would like to make this KPI metrics div fixed.

Below this KPI metrics is a div for tables. Now when the user scrolls through the table the KPI metrics div should always be fixed. I would also like to know how to align the KPI metrics div and the table div aligned on the right side. I have figured that I could add `position : fixed` for the KPI div. But not sure how to align the table div on the right side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <p>KPI DIV TO BE FIXED</p>
  <div class="row row-no-gutters">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">SIDEBAR</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">KPI DIV</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>TABLE DIV BELOW KPI DIV</p>
  <div class="row">

    <div class=" offset-md-4 col-md-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">TABLE DIV</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start for you:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/zXBVRp

I'm not clear where you need to go from here though. Let me know if you need more help.

The HTML is very close to what you posted, my only changes are on lines 21 and 23 where I modified the classes.

```
<div class="row row-no-gutters">

<div class=" col-md-offset-4 col-md-8" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">TABLE DIV</div>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I was if the table div is aligned on the right hand side.as in offset of 4 and column 8